# Set multiple cell values based on active cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been looking around a lot and can't seem to find a solution to this problem, so here goes. Basically, I have a judging form where users will input a series 6 scores, along with a project ID. I will then access this data from a separate spreadsheet, and use it in my primary spreadsheet. I will want to average the data etc. but that is not important. What I can't figure out for the life of me, is how to write to multiple cells in my main spreadsheet based on where I write my script.

That sounded a little confusing so let me clarify. Lets say I name my function `doThis`. `doThis` will take in a range, such as AA:AB, and then operate on it, taking averages etc. etc. I will put in my main spreadsheet, lets say in cell A1 `=doThis(exampleRange)` (where exampleRange may just be an import statement from another spreadsheet). I then want the data from `doThis` to be written to as many cells as are necessary. Basically, lets say there are three projects that have been judged, and for each project I want `doThis` to output three metrics.

I then want the data from `doThis` to be written from A1:C3, but only have to write `doThis(exampleRange)` in cell A1. As I said, I've searched quite a bit on this, but I'm almost certainly missing something, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Of course, if you need any clarification I am more than happy to help.

**EDIT FOR MORE INFO:** Alright, let me clarify my use case a little bit. Basically, the form has 8 different sheets, each for a different category. On the form, once selecting a category the judge then selects scores in 6 categories, and then submit it. That will all be in a SEPARATE spreadsheet. In my main spreadsheet, where I will be doing the data analysis, I want to have 3 columns per category, so a total of 24 columns in total. So I want to type `=doThis(respectiveRange)` at A1,D1,G1... etc.

The actual action of the code will be the same between all three, various metric computation etc, which is all simple enough. I want to have `doThis` to be able to write to as many rows as in its respective area as needed based on the number of responses, and want it to work whether I write it it A1, D1 or whatever. So while the example code below is good, I want the A1:C3 part of it to be dynamically set based on where the `=doThis(respectiveRange)` is placed in the spreadsheet, and on how many responses are in the respectiveRange. I might be explaining this in a confusing way, but I am definitely more than happy to keep on clarifying as long as it takes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the data from multiple cells.

```
function moveCells() {
  var sheetSource = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ShheetName');
  var twoDimensionalArrayOfSourceValues = sheetSource.getRange("A1:C3").getValues();
  var sourceValuesAsString = twoDimensionalArrayOfSourceValues.toString();

  sheetSource.getRange("A1").setValue(sourceValuesAsString);

};
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make the "A1:C3" part dynamic? Like, it could be as long as there are answers to the form. Also, the form will have multiple equivalent sheets for different categories, so I'll need to post the same code over at intervals of every 3 columns, but with different values. Basically, I need the A1:C3 part to not be static, but instead dynamically change based on the number of responses, and the placement of the `=doThis(exampleRange)`. But thanks, that is a great place to start!

Comment: If you had an "on submit trigger" that went to the response that was just written to the spreadsheet, you could find the last column by iterating through each cell to determine if there is a value present.  Doesn't a form only write one row at a time?  Are you looking to process multiple responses over a period of time, or some certain number?

Comment: I edited the original post with some more information about my use case. Its totally possible I just am thinking about my problem in an incorrect way, so if there is a better way to accomplish what I want I am all ears. Thanks so much!

Comment: I want to clarify, that I want to write to cells A1:C_ using a `=doThis(rangeOfValues)` placed at A1, I don't want to read from A1:C_, and then write their data to A1. If this is not possible in the way I envisage, I'd appreciate any other way to do it, which allows it to be expandable, and work for multiple categories, i.e. work whether I want to write to D1:F_, etc.etc.